# Recuperar tempo de expiração do cookie em javascript ou jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Existe alguma forma de recuperar o tempo restante para expiração de um cookie em javascript ou jquery?

Comment: Quando escreve "recuperar" quer dizer saber o tempo que tem? ou mudar (fazer set novamente)?

Comment: Quero saber quanto tempo falta para expirar.

Comment: Já experimentou `$.cookie('nome_do_cookie');`?

Comment: Sim e isso não trás um objeto cookie apenas o value dele.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você simplesmente não tem como obter esse tipo de informação com JavaScript pois ela não está disponível em `document.cookie`.

Porém, como existe gambiarra pra tudo, caso eja você quem esteja definindo esse cookie, você pode criar um segundo para servir de apoio, armazenando nele as datas de criação.

Comment: Pesquisei aqui tb e realmente é isso. Obrigado pela resposta

Comment: Também não tinha certeza sobre o assunto. Fiquei uns 40 minutos pesquisando e testando soluções alternativas sugeridas no SOen, confirmando em vários outros sites, blogs, listas de discussão etc. até chegar num parecer definitivo, inclusive com uma alternativa errada, porém viável. Queria apenas ter podido trazer algo de uma RFC, mas não encontrei nada no texto que dissesse especificamente isso.

Answer (score 5):

Já tem uma resposta aceite e de facto ela está correta pois não dá para ler essa informação.

Deixo mais uma resposta com uma ideia no caso de o Cookie ser criado por tí. Podes escrever a data de fim no próprio Cookie.

```
var data = new Date();
data.setSeconds(data.getSeconds() + 10); // Cookie com 10 segundos de vida
data = new Date(data);

$.cookie('meu_cookie', data, {
    expires: data
});
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/6pQ5T/

Nota que os Cookies podem ser mudados pelo utilizador, pelo que não são de confiar.

Comment: Muito boa resposta também. Sei dessa vulnerabilidade do cookie mas medi também o risco, pois a chave e valor do cookie são criptografados em ceaser. Qualquer alteração faz com que ele caia no block false do if.